# Angular 2+ Google Maps componente no muestra puntos dinamicos

Tags: angular

Estoy intentando implementar un mapa En angular 2  con el componente Google maps
pero tengo problemas al querer mostrar varios puntos  dinamicamente

les ajunto el codigo ( simulando mas o menos lo que quiero hacer )

- primero creo un array con los puntos

```html
  agregarpuntos(){
    let val= {
      lat : "14.048128",
      long :"-87.1973873"
    }

    let val1 = {
      lat: "14.0480916",
      long: "-87.1977186"
    }
  
    let val2 = {
      lat: "14.0484597",
      long: "-87.1988568"
    }

    let val3 = {
      lat: "14.0497273",
      long: "-87.1991785"
    }

    let val4 = {
      lat: "14.0508924",
      long: "-87.2028268"
    }

    this.listapuntos.push(val);
    this.listapuntos.push(val1);
    this.listapuntos.push(val2);
    this.listapuntos.push(val3);
    this.listapuntos.push(val4);


    console.log(this.listapuntos);

  }
```

desde el html mando a llamar la funcion con un boton

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="agregarpuntos()">Ver</button>
```

y en el mapa html

```html
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="15" >
               <div  *ngFor="let cliente of listapuntos">
                  <agm-marker [latitude]="cliente.lat" [longitude]="cliente.long"></agm-marker>
               </div>
 </agm-map>
```

pero no me muestra **ningún punto**  solo el mapa

que estoy haciendo mal ?

como datos extra ya importe en app.modules.ts

```html
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'Aqui esta mi apikey'
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

como extra  no se si importa o no  pero si coloco  la lat y long manualmente si funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de investigar en stackoverflow en ingles

encontré un comentario que decia que debia convertir la longitud y latitud a numero ya que al enviarlos desde un servicie estos venían como string

impletemente una funcion para convertir de string a numero

```html
  private convertStringToNumber(value: string): number {
    return +value;
  }
```

en el html la implemento

```html
             
            <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="10" >
                  <agm-marker *ngFor="let cliente of listapuntos" [latitude]="convertStringToNumber(cliente.lat)" [longitude]="convertStringToNumber(cliente.long)"></agm-marker>
            </agm-map>
```